# Mantis to Bugzilla migration?

Tags: migration, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mantis

So we have this project which uses Mantis as bug tracker tool and in the company the corporate bug tracking tool is Bugzilla. This means we will have to use Bugzilla soon.
I searched for tools that can be used to migrate from Mantis to Bugzilla and I only found this [m2bz](http://www.mehnle.net/software/m2bz) tool which seems  to work for Mantis 0.17.5 and Bugzilla 2.16.3 but seems also kind of dead since 2003...

Do you guys have already try to do such a migration? The Mantis version used is 1.1.8 and the Bugzilla one is 3.0.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load data with importxml.cgi, which implies that you only need to dump your existing database into the proper XML for the migration.

We usually migrate other Bugzilla installations into our big Bugzilla database with a script that copies the data from one db to another, mapping bug ids, users, etc.  I tried to do much the same thing when I had to migrate JIRA stuff.  It turned out to be a major PITA!

I would have been much, much better off working on how to dump JIRA in the correct XML.

The data model changed a lot between 2.16 and 3.X, so whatever m2bz tool you found probably won't do what you want.

Comment: The XML solution sounds pretty good to me and yes Ii can imagine how "PITAble" it should be to make the mapping from one DB to another ;)
Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the datbase structure for Mantis?

Because you can import sql scripts in the BugZilla database, to make the migration yourself.

Comment: Hi KLE ;)
No I don't know the way data is structured neither for Mantis nor for Bugzilla.
If there is no automatic solution to make the migration I will choose the manual one, but I would prefer to add a tool that's for sure!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Bugzilla database is:

http://www.faqs.org/docs/bugzilla/dbschema.html

I couldn't find it for Mantis though :-(